# Set widget icon in Customizer?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, widgets

[image]

Is it possible to switch the icon displayed under Customizer->Widgets for your custom widget plugin? Right now it displays a `+` as icon.

Thank you!

```
div#widget-tpl-widget-clock-widget-3 .widget-title:before {
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: dashicons;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of where the `+` icon displays?

Comment: The icons are just set with CSS. To change them enqueue a stylesheet that sets your own icon in the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` hook.

Comment: Added an image showing what I mean. @JacobPeattie are you sure you are talking about the widgets icon in the customizer? Because I don't understand how I would use that?

Comment: Yes. Inspect it with the dev tools and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @JacobPeattie yes I can manage to change the dashicons using the CSS I posted in the first post. But that requires the number after the widget, which feels like it can break the function, don't know where this number comes from. Isn't it possible to set this by editing the widget itself?